# How can improve http request performance on an iOS device during App start?

Tags: objective-c, time, request, afnetworking

I have an iOS app where I need to load a lot of stuff (JSON data, Images ...) initially after app start (after appdelegate calls the first view). Currently I am using AFNetworking for my requests (Async requests).

What I experienced is a big delay before the first request (3G connection - iPhone 4)  itself really starts. I measured the time from operation start to the first bits loaded and checked the answering time of the server. It takes between 2.5 and 4 seconds before the app even starts receiving the first bytes, server said the buildtime is about 0.03 seconds. I think that is a big delay, even if he might have to establish the 3G connection first.

I tested this also with other servers, methods (synchronous/asynchronous), with AFNetworing and simple NSURLRequest and it is always the first request that takes a lot of time.

So my question is, did anyone else experience this and is there a way to accelerate that?

Comment: How about not firing off a big expensive network request immediately after your app sets up.  Things just don't get up and running immediately.

Comment: Mobiles frequently turn their radios off to conserve power, unfortunately it does then take them a long time to turn the radio back on and to then establish sockets with servers. This can frequently be measured in seconds. Once the radio is on and warm, does the latency drop off for you back to a more reasonable number? If so, then I am afraid that there is little that can be done other than to keep the radio turned on which drains the battery. In that case you will be best off managing the radio latencies by caching data from previous calls/spinners/not making the call,holding socket open,etc